# Meteor useraccounts routes and route priority: how to ensure static routes are hit first?

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router

I am using meteor useraccounts along with iron-router but my guess is this would apply the same to flow-router.

With Meteor useraccounts you configure/add routes like signIn, forgotPWD, etc... via code like:

```
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {
    name: 'signin',
    path: '/login',
    template: 'myLogin',
    layoutTemplate: 'myLayout',
    redirect: '/user-profile',
});
```

This is all fine and dandy except I also want to allow for a root parameterized route like:

```
Router.route '/:rootParam',
  name: 'rootParam'
  controller: share.WikiController
  onBeforeAction: ->
    rootParam = @params.rootParam
    if rootParam in share.staticRoutes
      Router.go(rootParam)  
    else
      @next()
```

So if the user goes to a route with an item id it works but if they go to a static useraccounts route like /login things also work.

I find its always hitting the parameter route and the static routes never work.

Comment: It's usually easier if your parameterized routes are in a sub-folder, i.e. `/item/:itemid` otherwise you always have the ambiguity. Or you can do it the other way around and have `/user/login`. Another possibility is to grep the parameter in your item route and do `Router.go('signin')` as appropriate.

Comment: I've updated my example to show how I tried this. staticRoutes is just an array of static routes within useraccounts I want redirect to rather than treat as a paramterized variables. For some reason this doesn't work either and complains "Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?"  If I have this.next to always run it never goes to the signIn route. If I comment this whole route out, the signIn route works.

Comment: You can't do a `Router.go()` in a `onBeforeAction`. You can *render* the route however. You might also have to change the *layoutTemplate* if your named routes use different layouts.

Comment: While I fail to understand why Router.go doesn't work in an onBeforeAction or Action using the render approach did work for me... if you want to me marked as the correct answer you'll have to submit and answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a `Router.go()` in `onBeforeAction`. You can render the route however. You might also have to change the `layoutTemplate` if your named routes use different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd recommend is not overloading a section of your path if you can because this may cause confusion on which route will catch. Will `/:itemid` catch `/login`? It would make sense if you only saw the `/:itemid` route.

Try using something like `/items/:itemid` so that the `/login` and `/items` are static and unique.

```
Router.route('/items/:itemid', function () {
    var item = Items.findOne({_id: this.params.itemid});
    this.render('ShowItem', {data: item});
});
```

And if you really want to have `/` route to `/items/:itemid` you can still do a redirect in your route function.

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    //TODO: redirect to /items/:itemid
});
```

Comment: I agree with you and michel, the trouble for me is that I was using a parameterized root path before I was using the useraccounts package, so its a case of hindsight is 20/20

Comment: Then use my second pattern `/user/login`

Comment: Same deal, I have /:param/:param routes, and /:param/:param:/:param/:param routes... to some degree I think I am write because I do this to make the URLS more user friendly... effectively its: /:notebookName/:notebookID/:pageName/:pageId which I think is more firendly than /notebooks/:notebookName/:notebookID/:pageName/:pageId - so maybe the question has no answer beyond plan on this beforehand --- the really screwy thing is even if I put the AccountsTemplates.configureRoute stuff in a folder that loads first, the routes still don't register before the basic router code does